# Angularjs jQCloud does not show properly in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, word-cloud

I am using this [angularjs](https://github.com/mistic100/angular-jqcloud) plugin for Word Cloud. It works fine at everywhere. But, it doesn't show properly in Bootstrap Modal though it works fine in angular ui modal too. But, I need to work it at `Bootstrap Modal`. In my demo plunker, you'll see it works fine in any place:
[image]

But in Bootstrap modal, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I solve this?

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOnjR9RVIjrWI0WTp59D?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with simple CSS solution. Just need to add these hack code for modal:

```
.modal {
    display: block;     /* undo display:none          */
    height: 0;          /* height:0 is also invisible */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* no-overflow                */
}
.modal.fade.in {
  height: auto;         /* let the content decide it  */ 
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOnjR9RVIjrWI0WTp59D?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of this code in jQCloud.js:

```
word_size = {
  width: word_span.width(),
  height: word_span.height()
};
```

At the moment when your page is rendered, the popup is hidden, so elements have zero width and height and thus they're displayed in one place overlapping each other.

To solve this issue you should somehow delay displaying of your cloud till the moment the popup is shown. Below is one example of how to do that, but it's not the best one, I believe.

First, add `ng-click` callback to your button:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showCloud()" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open Popup
</button>
```

Amend your popup markup to show cloud some `$scope.isCloudVisible` property:

```
...
<div style="width: 500px; height: 350px;" ng-if="!isCloudVisible"></div>
<jqcloud words="words" width="500" height="350" steps="7" ng-if="isCloudVisible"></jqcloud>
...
```

First div is there as a placeholder, to show blank space while cloud is rendering (this is not so pretty, I agree).

In your controller create `showCloud()`callback and add `isCloudVisible` property:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  ...
  $scope.isCloudVisible = false; 
  $scope.showCloud = function() {      
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.isCloudVisible = true;
    }, 200);
  };      
});
```

Note, that I've added `$timeout` service to the controller arguments.

See working [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i1ntCy86HO0ItKVL1jfk?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your help. One issue I am facing now. Actually, in one page I have multiple modals and if one popup is open, other popup's jQcloud show like previous one. Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/oOnjR9RVIjrWI0WTp59D?p=preview
How to solve this?

Comment: Well, my solution is something like a proof of concept. Each of your modals should have it's own visibility properties and button callbacks. I would suggest writing a directive for that, with button and modal included in it.

Comment: Ok, got it, but the thing is, I am very new in angularjs. I can't write my own directive still now. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Actually, can it be solved by simple CSS? Please, check my this update of plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oOnjR9RVIjrWI0WTp59D?p=preview 
There are bootstrap tab at there. And at tab, as some tabs are hidden initially, rendering create similar problems. I have found at online a CSS hack code for solving this tab rendering issue(check the style.css please). Can similar kind of CSS be applied for Modal too?

Comment: actually, it can be solved by simple CSS only :), here is the update: http://plnkr.co/edit/oOnjR9RVIjrWI0WTp59D?p=preview
Thanks by the way for your time.

Comment: I'm glad that you've managed to find a simpler solution. Possibly you should make it an answer and accept it so others could use it too.

Comment: I have done this :) Thanks for your suggestion @Ilya Luzyanin